# VirtualBox Goes Black after 1-2 hours

Tags: virtualbox

I am having issues about running multiple VMs at the same time.

On my home PC I am running 150 instances at the same time with and i7 core CPU and 64GB ram.

But on my dedicated server I can just run  only 30  instances.

They seem to be running but when I try to show the machines I get black screens.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are they sleeping/hibernating? Try going into the virtual machines (Ubuntu? Windows?) and make sure they are not set to shut off monitors or go to sleep.

Comment: It's Ubuntu in VMs.
Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: Also window screen disappears after 1-2 minutes after I press Show button on Virtualbox

Comment: @ Gloria, Please provide version of Ubuntu but generally it is in System Settings - Power